# Making a program into two different classes

Tags: java

So I had to write a code that takes a word and reverse it I got it to work but for my homework I had to make it into two classes a tester class and a main class how do I do that?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  String original = "";
  String reverse = "";
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
  original = in.nextLine();

  int length = original.length();

  for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
  {
     reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
  }
  System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse);
}
```

Comment: do you have input what this "tester class" shall test?

Comment: well the main class is supposed to have the program and then the tester class is supposed to run the program I don't know if that makes any sense

Comment: ah so you are not opting for something like a jUnit test but - > your "testerClass" contains your main method and calls a method of your "mainClass" which contains the input/output and String reversion - do I understand this right?

Comment: yes that is what i have to do

Answer (score 1):

You create two classes. You can even put a main method in both of them.

```java
public class Homework {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Code here to prompt user for string and to print reversed string
    }
    static String reverse(String input) {
        // Code here to do the actual reverse logic, returning reversed string
    }
}
```

```java
public class HomeworkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("Hello", "olleH");
        test("This is a test", "tset a si sihT");
    }
    private static void test(String input, String expected) {
        String rev = Homework.reverse(input);
        System.out.println(input + ": " + rev);
        if (! expected.equals(rev))
            System.out.println("  ** NOT AS EXPECTED: " + expected);
    }
}
```

You can now run the `Homework` for manual testing, or the `HomeworkTest` class for automatic testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the original String in the Main-class and hand it to the second class to execute the for-loop. The second class then returns the reversed String so that the Main-Class can print it out.

The second class could contain a static method which reverses the String (executes the for-loop) or you can create an object of the second class and and this Object the original String to reverse.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Most trivially, you could make a static function in a Test class, like so:

```
class Test
{
    public static void runTest(String args[])
    {
        //same as your above program
    }
}
```

But that is probably not what your teacher wants.  Instead, you could make a Test class that reverses a set of strings.

```
class Test
{
    public static void runTests()
    {
        //iterate through a list of hard-coded strings to test
    }
}
```

You would then make a separate function in a `Reverser` class and the `Test.runTests()` function would test the `Reverser` class.

However, there are standardized ways of doing this.  One common way is called JUnit.  If you are using Eclipse, try [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to

1. Divide your code into a function `public String reverse(String input)`
2. Create new Tester class
3. Add test method in tester class `public void test()`
4. Prepare assertions to test your function `assert reverse("ola").equals("alo") : "First assertion failed"`
5. In main function run `new Tester().test();`
6. To make assertions working you have to run jvm with -ea option